# Preserving order of the keys while iterating over a subset of a dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to remove keys from a dictionary:

```
incomes = {'apple': 5600.00, 'orange': 3500.00, 'banana': 5000.00}
non_citric = {k: incomes[k] for k in incomes.keys() - {'orange'} }
non_citric
```

output:

```
{'banana': 5000.0, 'apple': 5600.0}
```

I am however confused as to why the original order of the keys is not preserved

Comment: The problem is unclear, what did you expect? This result is quite logic.

Comment: Orders aren't maintained for sets :)

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: As of Python 3.6, for the CPython implementation of Python, dictionaries remember the order of items inserted. This is considered an implementation detail in Python 3.6; you need to use OrderedDict if you want insertion ordering that's guaranteed across other implementations of Python (and other ordered behavior). So this behavior is highly likely if you are using an older version of python. Moreover, `dict` is not the right data structure to use if maintaining order is your goal. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6

Comment: see also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared

Comment: @AkshaySehgal the set created by `incomes.keys() - {'orange'}` must be ordered correctly, too. Why isn't guranteed, even in 3.6+.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want to remove one (or several) keys while maintaining the original order of the keys.

Then you could modify your code to:

```
incomes = {'apple': 5600.00, 'orange': 3500.00, 'banana': 5000.00}
non_citric = {k: incomes[k] for k in incomes if k not in {'orange'}}
# or
# non_citric = {k: v for k,v in incomes.items() if k not in  {'orange'}}
non_citric
```

Why did it fail? When you run `incomes.keys() - {'orange'}`, the output `{'apple', 'banana'}` is a set, that is unordered.

In your particular case, you could also use:

```
non_citric = incomes.copy()
non_citric.pop('orange')
```

Comment: I will request you vote to reopen if you are answering as well, instead of voting to close. Other answers might be more illuminating.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal I already did that ;) only 1 vote is missing